# Can anyone help me identify this pipe in my engine bay?

Tags: part-identification, oil-leak, astra

[image]

Hi.

This pipe has recently developed an oil leak. It is the one I have highlighted in red. Cannot seem to get a definitive answer as to what the pipe actually is.

Can anyone help me identify it before I take it to the garage?

The car is a 2015 Astra Bi-Turbo 2.0L

Thanks.[image][image][image]

Comment: The EGR feed from the exhaust?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of the turbo output pipes to me.

Can you see where the other end of the rubber hose goes to?  Does it go to the intercooler?

There should be compressed air flowing that pipe, not oil.

Maybe your turbo is leaking oil and you have an air leak on that pipe so the oil is being blown out.

Can you take another photo viewed from the left of that photo?

Comment: Hi. I have added a couple more photos. One from the left like requested and one that shows the oil leak. Thanks.

Comment: That is definitely the turbo that the pipe is connected to.  It is not clear to me where the oil is coming from maybe you could clean that area down and keep an eye on it.  However if your turbo is leaking oil you may need to do something about it soon.  Best to get someone to look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I have contacted the garage where I bought the car from and they are going to get it sorted for me. Only bought the car 2 months ago so they have agreed to rectify it free of charge. Could the turbo explode if not dealt with quickly? Thanks again.

Comment: It could break-up inside which could cause fragments to be sucked into the engine and cause damage to the engine.

Comment: That doesn’t sound great. Hopefully they will get it sorted at the garage.

Answer (score 0):

The pipe itself has no oil lines in it, its there to carry the air which has been drawn in and compressed by the turbo compressor.

That pipe is attached to the compressor outlet side of the turbo, the pipe runs from there to the intercooler and then the air continues on to the engine intake manifold.

Considering the location of the turbo, there is nothing above it that could leak oil down onto it.

Its highly likely then that the turbo itself is leaking oil which means it will need new oil seal and be rebuilt. Replacement would be advised.

Of course, take it into a qualified mechanic and get a proper inspection.